# React Electron HTTP request from main

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, http, electron

I am having a CORS issue when running my request through the frontend, and through some reading, I found that I could resolve those issues by making my calls from my main. I am using electron with react and the problem I am facing is that I can not set my firebase auth cookie like i was when I was making the call through the frontend.  I am also using react query to make my calls.  When i console.log my endpoint, I can see that I am receiving the request to create the cookie,  but when I look in my devtools at the cookie, its not set.  Could it be because I am calling the function from a node environment now?  Thanks for any help as I have been stuck on this issue for days.

Here is my react query call to my preload.js file.  From there, it proceeds to go to my main.js where the http request is made

Signin.jsx

```
const { mutateAsync: sessionSignIn, isLoading: sessionSignInLoading } =
  useMutation({
    mutationFn: window.auth.sessionSignIn,
    //mutationFn: apiV2.account.SignIn, <------ this works when calling from front end
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["userGetFromSession"] });
      navigate("/entity");
    },
    onError: () => {
      toast.error("Unauthorized");
    },
  });

const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await firebaseSignIn({ email, password }).then((userCredentials) => {
    sessionSignIn(userCredentials.user.accessToken);
  });
};
```

preload.jsx

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('auth', {
  sessionSignIn: (args) = >ipcRenderer.invoke('session', args),
  authorize: async() = >{
    await ipcRenderer.invoke('authorization')
  }
})
```

main.js

```
ipcMain.handle('session', async(event, args) = >{
  return await apiV2.account.signIn(args)
})

ipcMain.handle('authorization', async() = >{
  const results = await apiV2.entity.get.authorized() return results.data
})
```

this is where it authenticates on my backend
requireAuthorized.js

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin') const {
  ClientError
} = require('../utilities')

async
function requireAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

  console.log(res.locals.user)

  if (!res.locals.user) {
    return next(new ClientError(401, 'No user found for this request session'))
  }

  const firebaseUserRecord = await firebase.auth().getUser(res.locals.user.firebaseUid)

  if (!firebaseUserRecord.emailVerified) {
    return next(new ClientError(401, 'Account not confirmed', 'The user for this session has not yet confirmed their account', {
      accountConfirmRequired: true
    }))
  }

  next()
}

module.exports = requireAuthenticated
```

my end point

```
router.post('/signIn', jsonBodyParser, validators.signInBody, async(req, res, next) = >{
  const {
    idToken
  } = req.body

  try {
    await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken, true)
  } catch {
    return next(new ClientError(401, 'Invalid or revoked id token'))
  }

  const firebaseSessionCookie = await firebase.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {
    expiresIn: sessionCookie.getDefaultExpiresIn()
  })

  sessionCookie.set(firebaseSessionCookie, res, req.headers)

  return res.status(200).end()
})

router.post('/signOut', requireAuthenticated, async(req, res) = >{
  const firebaseSessionCookie = sessionCookie.get(req) sessionCookie.clear(res)

  if (firebaseSessionCookie) {
    const decodedCookie = await firebase.auth().verifySessionCookie(firebaseSessionCookie, false) await firebase.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(decodedCookie.uid)
  }

  return res.status(200).json({
    success: true
  })
})
```